# How to get Primitive Array from ES6 Promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise, twgl.js

I am trying to load glsl scripts as strings using the ES6 Promise and Fetch APIs. I thought I had a pretty elegant solution for getting the vertex and fragment shaders and creating a new programInfo with twgl.js

```
Promise.all([fetch(vert_url),fetch(frag_url))])
       .then((responses) => responses.map((response) => response.text()))
       .then((sources) => this.programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, sources));
```

The problem is that it seems that response.text() is returning a Promise rather than a raw string. Inside `twgl.createProgramInfo()` it runs sources through a map, and then attempts to run indexOf on the results.

```
function createProgramInfo(gl, shaderSources, ...) {
    ...
    shaderSources = shaderSources.map(function (source) {
      // Lets assume if there is no \n it's an id
      if (source.indexOf("\n") < 0) {
      ...
```

Chrome throws a javascript error on the final line there:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: source.indexOf is not a function
```

I can't seem to figure out how to turn `sources` into real strings. Anybody have an idea how to get this working?

**Note**: This is actually in a React app created using **create-react-app**, that means webpack and babel are being used to transpile this from jsx.

Comment: @4castle Maybe consider turning your comment into an answer so this thread can be closed

Comment: @4castle 's answer is correct but from an implementation perspective, why not just combine the `then`s since the first one is not doing any async behavior?

Comment: @Damon If they don't use two `then` calls, they will end up with nested callbacks, which is unnecessary with promises.

Comment: @4castle how so? you can just pass the map into `createProgramInfo` in the first `then`, something like `this.programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, responses.map(_=>_.text()))` since there is no point in promisifying a synchronous map.

Comment: @Damon According to the OP, `.text()` returns a promise, not the actual string which their function expects, so there has to be another `.then` which waits for those promises.

Comment: @4castle cool - misread that part +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to convert an array of promises into a promise of an array, use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
Promise.all([fetch(vert_url), fetch(frag_url)])
       .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(response => response.text())))
       .then(sources => this.programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, sources));
```

[`Promise#then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) will evaluate the promise you return in the callback from `Promise.all`, and will make the next call to `.then` evaluate to the array of sources, which is what your code expects.

---

With a promise library like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html), you can use [`Promise.map`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) in order to make this more readable.

```
Promise.all([fetch(vert_url), fetch(frag_url)])
       .map(response => response.text())
       .then(sources => this.programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, sources));
```

Comment: Nice, never heard of this technique, but one could also use `arguments` and not require an extra promise? Seems a little bit like abusing promises.

Comment: @JuanMendes Perhaps you should post your own answer? This code is pretty straightforward (it's not some special technique), but if you know of another way, please share.